# detect iPhone code error

Tags: jquery

I am trying to redirect my page if it is being viewed on an iPhone 5.

Here is the UPDATED current code:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>TEST</title>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var isiPhone = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone");
    var iHeight = window.screen.height;

if (isiPhone > -1 && iHeight <= 1336) {
    window.location("index2.html");
}
});
</script>

Start Page

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't edit your code every time somebody points out a minor syntax error.  Not only does that render the answers meaningless, it's unfair to those trying to help.  Please also review this material:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're also going to have to be a lot more forthcoming with your problem description.  Dumping the code while only saying, _"it's failing"_ is unacceptable.  Explain exactly _how_ it fails?  What troubleshooting steps have you performed?  Have you validated the HTML?  Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: **Just after `</head>`, you are missing the opening body tag `<body>`**.

Comment: Sorry - only just joined and not sure how things work around here :)

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle you can play with.  The logic seems to be working:  http://jsfiddle.net/tKXQ7/

Comment: @Sparky, I added the missing <body> tag and visited the jsfiddle link you suggested.  It says my phone is an iPhone and that the height is under 1336. The code now seems correct but refuses to redirect??  How can I now show you my current code for mistakes>  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Read [the documentation I linked previously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).  example: `window.location = "http://www.mozilla.org";`

Comment: I just changed the window.location line of code to the example you gave and it still refuses to redirect?  How on earth can it be so complex to get a simple redirect to work :(

Comment: Either your `<script>` tag contains code OR it has a `src` attribute, but it **cannot** have both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed a huge error.  Either your `<script>` tag contains code OR it has a `src` attribute, but it **cannot** have both...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // your code
    });
    // your code cannot be inside a JavaScript file include
    // this needs to be totally empty!
</script>
```

Instead, you must do this.

Notice the empty set of `<script></script>` tags for the JavaScript file includes..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // your code in here
</script>
```

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion - and it now works!  Thank you for all of your help - I thought I was going crazy.   :)

Answer (score 0):

You had extra parenthesis.

```
if(isiPhone > -1) && (iHeight <= 1336) {
```

Should be:

```
if ( isiPhone > -1 && iHeight <= 1336 ) {
```

EDIT:

Try debugging the code to see why it isn't working:

```
var isiPhone = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone");
var iHeight = window.screen.height;

if (isiPhone > -1 && iHeight <= 1336) {
    window.location.replace("index2.html")
} else {
    console.log('Is this browser an iPhone: ' + ((isiPhone > -1) ? 'yes' : 'no'));
    console.log('Is the height <= 1336: ' + ((iHeight <= 1336) ? 'yes' : 'no'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but that still refuses to work??

Comment: Ok, I have changed my code as suggested - but the page still fails to redirect.  What is the console.log code? and how do I few it on my iPhone?  Thank you.

Comment: @RicSum, I don't know how you'd use the console from an iPhone.  However, why can't you troubleshoot and test the logic from your desktop computer?  Get the logic working on desktop and adjust parameters for iPhone.  You can also change the user-agent of your desktop Safari (under the Developer's menu) to the Mobile Safari user agent and test like that as well.